# Sum of last week's sales for custom 52/53 week date table in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I'm trying to create a measure to calculate the sum of last week's sales. My calendar is custom and held in a date table, starting in February and can be either 52 or 53 week years.

The code below is from this handy youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jclWnA7pEvY) but I can't work out how to accomodate anything for week 1 if I'm not in a 52 week year.

In the code below, [Week_WOY] is a number from 1-53, and [Year_Uid] is the year - e.g. 2015,2016 etc.

I'm creating my tabular model in VS and then accessing using PowerBI in Live Query mode after deployment. Annoyingly that means I can't use some DAX expressions (e.g. SELECTEDVALUE).

Logically I think I want to:
a) decide if the current week is week 1
b) find the number of weeks in the previous year
c) return the sum of sales for that (b) week number

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
LastWeekTest:=

VAR CurrentWeek = IF ( HASONEVALUE ( 'Date'[Week_WOY]), VALUES ( 'Date'[Week_WOY]) )
VAR CurrentYear = IF ( HASONEVALUE ( 'Date'[Year_Uid] ), VALUES ( 'Date'[Year_Uid] ) )
VAR MaxWeekNumber = CALCULATE(MAX('Date'[Week_WOY]), All('Date'))

RETURN
SUMX(
    FILTER(ALL('Date'),

IF(CurrentWeek = 1,
('Date'[Week_WOY] = MaxWeekNumber&& 'Date'[Year_Uid] = CurrentYear - 1),        
('Date'[Week_WOY] = CurrentWeek - 1 && 'Date'[Year_Uid] = CurrentYear)


)),
'Sales'[Sales - Inc VAT £]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to add a column to your date table. That column is what I would call WeekIndex. This is a value that increments by 1 every week. I don't have a setup for a 52/53 week date dim, but you can see an example of this type of column in [my DimDate](https://github.com/baldiniunlimited/daxdates). With a column like this, you can write a measure like below:

```
Sales = SUM ( 'Sales'[Sales - Inc VAT £] )
```

```
Sales Prior Week =
VAR PriorWeek = MAX ( 'Date'[WeekIndex] ) - 1
RETURN
  CALCULATE (
    [Sales],
    ALL ( 'Date' ),
    'Date'[WeekIndex] = PriorWeek
  )
```

Deriving a [WeekIndex] is usually pretty straightforward if you already have a date dimension. It's usually easiest to do a distinct count of Year-Week pairs less than current week.

Else, if you want to avoid enhancing your model for some reason:

```
Sales Prior Week =
VAR CurrentWeek = MAX ( 'Date'[Week_WOY] )
VAR CurrentYear = MAX ( 'Date'[Year_Uid] )
VAR PriorYear = IF ( CurrentWeek = 1, CurrentYear - 1, CurrentYear )
VAR PriorWeek =
  IF (
    CurrentWeek = 1,
    CALCULATE (
      MAX ( 'Date'[Week_WOY] ),
      ALL ( 'Date' ),
      'Date'[Year_Uid] = PriorYear
    ),
    CurrentWeek - 1
  )
RETURN
  CALCULATE (
    [Sales],
    ALL ( 'Date' ),
    'Date'[Year_Uid] = PriorYear,
    'Date'[Week_WOY] = PriorWeek
  )
```

In general, I like to implement time intelligence using `MAX` to get the current value, rather than a `SELECTEDVALUE` or an `IF ( HASONEVALUE, ...)`. This aligns with the way that the built in time intelligence functions are implemented.

Also, `SELECTEDVALUE` is in later releases of Tabular. If you're feeling pain for its lack, you should push for an upgrade.

Comment: Thank you, this is excellent. Happily I arrived at the first part of your answer organically this morning after smashing my head against a wall all weekend so it's good to have the validation that its the right approach. I used dense_rank in the source view to having a running week_number count.

I'm very new to DAX and the second part of your answer is incredibly helpful. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: @greggyb. This works perfect! I tried this and it works for getting results weekly. I need in addition to drill down to the day per day data while showing the results in weekly bunches. How can I do that?